# How can I write certain sections of text from different lines to multiple lines?

Tags: csv, file-writing

So I'm currently trying to use Python to transform large sums of data into a neat and tidy .csv file from a .txt file. The first stage is trying to get the 8-digit company numbers into one column called 'Company numbers'. I've created the header and just need to put each company number from each line into the column. What I want to know is, how do I tell my script to read the first eight characters of each line in the .txt file (which correspond to the company number) and then write them to the .csv file? This is probably very simple but I'm only new to Python!

So far, I have something which looks like this:

```
with open(r'C:/Users/test1.txt') as rf:
    with open(r'C:/Users/test2.csv','w',newline='') as wf:
        outputDictWriter = csv.DictWriter(wf,['Company number'])
        outputDictWriter.writeheader()
        rf = rf.read(8)
        for line in rf:
            wf.write(line)
```

Comment: The line `rf = rf.read(8)` looks wrong. You've change `rf` from an identifier of the whole input file to an identifier of its first 8 characters.

Comment: Okay thanks, so rf = rf.read(8) should read something like Line = rf.read(8)? What else would need to be changed?

Comment: Before I answer, I'd like to know if this is a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be 1) read the file in, 2) make the relevant transformation, and then 3) write the results to file. I don't have sample data, so I can't verify whether my solution exactly addresses your case

```
with open('input.txt','r') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read()

list_of_IDs = []
for line in file_content.split('\n')
    print("line = ",line)
    print("first 8 =", line[0:8])
    list_of_IDs.append(line[0:8])

with open("output.csv", "w") as file_handle:  
    file_handle.write("Company\n")
    for line in list_of_IDs:
        file_handle.write(line+"\n")
```

The value of separating these steps is to enable debugging.